# Error "Class VCWeakObjectHolder is implemented in both..." is crashing debug sessions

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, ios-simulator

I am getting following error all the time in my iOS app:

> objc[56232]: Class VCWeakObjectHolder is implemented in both
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AVConference.framework/Frameworks/ViceroyTrace.framework/ViceroyTrace
>   (0x12fe564d0) and
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AVConference.framework/AVConference
>   (0x12ef82e38). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

The app itself runs fine but the debugger will not attach to the device process. The simulator does attach but the app crashes immediately after a breakpoint is hit.

I am running out of ideas on how to deal with it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try: Clean (Alt Command Shift K), then close and reopen XCode. Then Build and run.

Comment: @GerdCastan Tried several times also with manual delete of *Derived Data* and restarts of the whole compute. Works when I get lucky, like 1 time out of 10 and then gets broken again after a few builds.

Comment: The trick is the sequence: The model I have in my mind is that XCode caches derived data. When you delete derived data, it is still in the cache and causes problems. This is why you restart xcode after deleting derived data. This sequence helps me in many more cases than only deleting derived data.

Comment: @GerdCastan, you should put this as an answer so it can be upvoted. I don't think it's a true answer, as this shouldn't be happening; however, your suggested sequence does work well in many cases, not just this one!

Comment: Submit a bug to Apple and reference my issue. #43377301
https://bugreport.apple.com/

Answer (score 3):

Simulator -> Hardware -> Erase all content and Settings...Works for me.

Comment: From Review: Would you please better describe exactly why would this solve the issue? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I submitted bug #43377301 to https://bugreport.apple.com/

**Debug messages should be off in Apple frameworks (Class VCWeakObjectHolder)**

I'm currently fixing bugs in an old code base and I have no idea what this internal Apple "warning" means.

It shouldn't be displayed to the 3rd party developer. I'm using CoreBluetooth and Objective-C.